# How to see the 'finished App' details in web UI after restarting Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to inspect an Spark App through web UI after it has finished. So I set the `spark.eventLog.enabled` to true and then set the `spark.eventLog.dir` to a local directory. Then when I click on completed application name it shows me the details of App. But when I reset the OS and run the Spark again it does't show me the finished Apps. I check out the `spark.eventLog.dir` directory and see that the details of finished app was there, but I don't know how to use this folder again to see it in web UI?

Comment: spark version? how are you setting spark.eventLog.enabled and spark.eventLog.dir??

Comment: Spar 1.2.0; I set in `spark-submit` command

Comment: you are using spark on yarn on in standalone mode??

Comment: I don't use yarn or mesos, I use spark Standalone mode and just for test in one machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting Spark clears the list of completed applications, Spark only retains them in memory.

When you want to inspect older applications, you have to start the history server from `/path/to/spark/sbin/start-history-server.sh /path/to/event-log`.

More info here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html